# What is the difference between Actionscript and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, actionscript-3, mootools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the key differences between JavaScript and ActionScript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268276/what-are-the-key-differences-between-javascript-and-actionscript-3)

Can you please give me some clarity on difference between ActionScript and JavaScript..
And what is flex? is it an ActionScript library like like jQuery and Mootools to the JavaScript. I have visisted Flex official website, there I have seen my favourite word "Opensource" tagged and also tag with "60 days trial version". I want to know what is ActionScript and what is Flex. Can i use DOM manipulation as want using ActionScript like developers play with DOM using jQuery and Mootools, Prototype etc...

I Don't have knowledge on Actionscript. Please someone explain it clearly.

Comment: Well, do you know what Flash is?

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Yes, I know bit about flash ...

Comment: To put it very simply, ActionScript is closely related to Flash as well as Flex, while JavaScript is more directly related to a browser.

Comment: Is it possible to do DOM manipulation with Actionscript.

Comment: javascript is **interpreted** by the **browser**, while actionscript is **compiled** into actionscript bytecode which runs under the Actionscript Virtual Machine in the Flash Player **browser plugin**. You can compile actionscript into swf files using Flash Professional,Flash Builder(Flex IDE) or the opensource FlexSDK which comes with a command line compiler. Flex also refers to a components framework for application development written in actionscript (think lots of controls/containers/etc.). You can code Flex using actionscript or the xml based tag based MXML.

Comment: In actionscript you have a Display List you can easily add/remove/nest display element. What do you mean by DOM manipulation ? Manipulating the DOM of the html page a SWF is embedded onto ? If so, there is an ExternalInterface available for Actionscript/Javascript communication.

Comment: To be pedantic: only ActionScript 3 is compiled. Actionscript 1 and 2 are interpreted by Flash Player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionScript is the primary programming language of Adobe's Flash Platform.

Flex is an Open Source SDK (Software Development Kit) for building Flash Platform Applications.  The Flash Platform runtimes are primarily Adobe AIR and and the Adobe Flash Player browser plugin.

The Flex SDK includes a command line compiler and an ActionScript UI Framework.  The UI Framework would be similar, at a high level, to something like JQuery.  Most people use Flex as a generic term to refer to all things Flex without specifying "Flex Framework" of "Flex Compiler".

Adobe also provides a commercial IDE named Flash Builder which is used by many to build Flex applications.  The 60 day trial you saw was probably for Flash Builder.  However, you are more than welcome to use the command line compiler as part of the open source SDK without a purchase of Flash Builder.

JavaScript on the other hand is a language implemented inside web browsers; primarily for modifying a web page without having to reload the whole page.

Both languages are ECMA compliant; so share very similar syntax.  The object model would be radically different, though.

Since you asked if it was possible to DOM manipulation with ActionScript; I'll say that it depends what you mean.  You wouldn't be able to use ActionScript to modify an HTML page's DOM.  But, you can use ActionScript to modify and extend the display hierarchy of a Flash movie (SWF).

Comment: I am glad to have your answer for my Question. I have seen your profile. Thank you stack overflow.